# Add Key Usage to CertificateSigningInfo in Java

Tags: java, rsa, asn.1, csr, pkcs#10

I am trying to add Key Usage to `certificateSigningInfo` in Java without using BouncyCastle. I have the following method which will create `certificateSigningInfo` that can be further signed to create PKCS#10:

```
public static byte[] createCertificationRequestInfo(X500Name x500Name, PublicKey publicKey) throws IOException {
    final DerOutputStream der1 = new DerOutputStream();
    der1.putInteger(BigInteger.ZERO);
    x500Name.encode(der1);
    der1.write(publicKey.getEncoded());

    // der encoded certificate request info
    final DerOutputStream der2 = new DerOutputStream();
    der2.write((byte) 48, der1);
    byte[] toReturn = der2.toByteArray();
    der2.close();
    return toReturn;
}
```

I am trying to add Key Usage with adding the following:

```
    KeyUsageExtension ku = new KeyUsageExtension();
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.NON_REPUDIATION, true);
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.KEY_ENCIPHERMENT, true);
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE, true);
    ku.encode(der1);
```

The `certificateSigningInfo` is created but it can't be validate as it has some missing values...

For example, the following CSR is created:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What library are you using for `DerOutputStream`, and why can you use it but not bouncycastle? Also, do you have a reference for "certificate signing info"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PKCS10 type `CertificationRequestInfo`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986#section-4) can't directly contain an `Extension`, or even `Extensions` (which is `SEQUENCE OF Extension`). Instead it can contain `Attributes` which is `SET OF Attribute` each of which is `SEQUENCE` of OID and `SET OF` values constrained by a notional InfoSet, or in the old syntax `ANY DEFINED BY --metaspec`. *One* possible Attribute is [PKCS9 5.4.2 `extensionRequest`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2985#page-17) which does contain `Extensions` which can include the one for `KeyUsage`.

Thus to add this to a PKCS10 you need something like the following. And as long as you are using the undocumented and possibly unreliable `sun.security` classes, there is one for PKCS10 that replaces most of the code you posted.

```
import sun.security.pkcs.*;
import sun.security.pkcs10.*; // separate in j8 (and later? not checked) 
import sun.security.util.*;
import sun.security.x509.*;

    // dummy setup; replace as appropriate
    X500Name name = new X500Name("O=Widgets Inc, CN=testcert");
    KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    gen.initialize(1024); KeyPair pair = gen.generateKeyPair();
    
    KeyUsageExtension ku = new KeyUsageExtension();
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.NON_REPUDIATION, true);
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.KEY_ENCIPHERMENT, true);
    ku.set(KeyUsageExtension.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE, true);
    CertificateExtensions exts = new CertificateExtensions();
    exts.set(KeyUsageExtension.IDENT,ku);
    PKCS10Attribute extreq = new PKCS10Attribute (PKCS9Attribute.EXTENSION_REQUEST_OID, exts);
    
    PKCS10 csr = new PKCS10 (pair.getPublic(), new PKCS10Attributes (new PKCS10Attribute[]{ extreq }));
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA"); // or adapt to key 
    signer.initSign(pair.getPrivate());
    csr.encodeAndSign(name, signer);

    // dummy output; replace 
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("SO49985805.der");
    out.write(csr.getEncoded()); out.close();
```

Comment: I hate to see more examples using the internal sun.* classes. My take on the original SO vision means we're not obligated to give questioners whatever they want on their terms, we're trying to create a valuable searchable archive for programmers coming around in the future.