Generate Certificate Signing Request in Java without Bouncy Castle
I am looking at an option to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using Java. A very easy and popular option is to use the BouncyCastle library as shown below. However the BouncyCastle provider seems to have a few known vulnerabilities which as shown below
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.70
and unfortunately this is being flagged as a Security Alert on our side.
Is there an option to do this using another options like native JDK functions?
As far as possible would like to avoid directly calling CLI instructions in Java like openssl or keytool.
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
 
// generate key
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
 
// create subject
X500Name subject = new X500Name("C=DE, O=MY ORG, OU=My Org Platform Clients, OU=<Some GUILD>, L=<Location>, CN=<common name> ");
 
// create CSR
JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, keyPair.getPublic());
PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = builder.build();
 
// save csr as local file
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_csr.csr")) {
    fos.write(csr.getEncoded());
    System.out.println("CSR your_csr.csr");
}


Bouncy stopped issuing jdk15on a while back, but if you use current versions (1.78.1 or 1.79) of jdk18on or jdk15to18 those have no known vulns. And preferably the first, because if you are actually using Java below 1.8-call-me-8 that will give much worse vulns than Bouncy. However there are unsupported Sun classes that work for now; see (my) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985805/add-key-usage-to-certificatesigninginfo-in-java and middle part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350607/java-api-to-create-a-keystore-and-attaching-a-csr-and-keypair-to-it

Is there a specific reason you're using bcprov-jdk15on instead of bcprov-jdk18on?
